# Simple DNScrypt not running anymore

Tags: dnscrypt

I used to use `simplednscrypt`.  It used to run just fine

Recently it doesn't work anymore. It works in one admin account. It doesn't work in another admin account or the local account.

Basically, nothing happens. No windows show up.

Update: Using the x86 version fixed the issue. I wonder what exactly went wrong with 64 issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Update: Using the x86 version fix the issue. I wonder what exactly went wrong with 64 issues.

First, uninstall Simple DNSCrypt from Program and Features.

Then delete `dnscrypt-proxy.toml.bak` in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Reinstall DNSCrypt

[source](https://github.com/bitbeans/SimpleDnsCrypt/issues/444#issuecomment-567028634)